# Tic Tac Toe Tie Condition C++

Tags: c++

I can't seem to get this function to work correctly. You would assume since I check for vertical, horizontal and diagonal if those don't get a win it would be a tie, but my program says its a tie after I fill in the Top left box and the middle box. Any suggestions? Do I have to change the way I search for vertical horizontal and diagonal?

Here is my code for this function:

```
char winningLetter;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2])
    {
        winningLetter = board[i][0];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[1][i] == board[2][i])
    {
        winningLetter = board[0][i];
    }
}
if ((board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2]) ||
   (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0]))
    {
        winningLetter == board[1][1];
    }

if (winningLetter == 'X')
{
    cout << "Player One is the winner!" << endl;
}
else if (winningLetter == 'O')
{
    cout << "Player Two is the winner!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "The game is a tie!" << endl;
    tie = true;
}

return;
```

Comment: You also need to check whether the tiles are empty, and break out of the loop as soon as you have a winner.

Comment: `winningLetter` may be used uninitialized.

Comment: `winningLetter == board[1][1]` this is soo wrong.

Comment: @n0rd: No, that part is right.  You can win on the diagonal only if you own the center.

Comment: What? It's the comparison where assignment is supposed to be (in the body of `if` statement).

Comment: You should be able to debug the code by yourself, and only then post questions if you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is having the wrong conditions for a tie.

The condition is not

- There is no winner

but

- The game is over and there is no winner

You never checked if the game is over.